# Unable to load data in HDFS with caret (é, Ö)

Tags: hadoop, character-encoding, hdfs, teradata

I am trying to load a table from Teradata to Hive. The data contains special characters such as (é, Ö). When I load this into HDFS, the file replaces these characters with '?', '☐' etc.
The file's encoding is UTF-8 when opened in notepad++. I am using Talend Big Data studio for above operation.

1. Text File loaded in HDFS is in UTF-8 encoding.
   2.The data that's being put in HDFS is like below. 'ef bf bd' is replaced wherever it faces above characters.

   > > 0000120:    30 7c 56 ef bf bd 43 4c 41 56 20 45 4c 47 52 7c   0|V...CLAV ELGR|

expected outcome : VÀCLAV
received outcome in HIVE : V�CLAV

3. Teradata side, the column has character set as ASCII.

Does anybody have idea how to solve this issue? Does UTF-8 contain LATIN character set as well ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We have no idea what character encoding your program expects or what the data on your disk contains. You will want to [edit] the question to provide enough details for someone who understands these issues to see what you are working on. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Comment: Note in particular that Windows editors are notoriously bad at correctly determining the character set of a piece of text.

Comment: The accents you show are not [carets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret) in either case. é has an acute accent and Ö has a diaeresis (also know as trema or umlaut). An example of a character with a caret would be â.

Comment: Find out what the encoding in Teradata actually is.  `SHOW TABLE <your table>`.  Find the the column in question, see what the encoding is. Once you know that, you should be able to set the character set for your Hive table correctly.

Comment: I have provided more information. Can someone look at it and provide a solution?

Comment: The problem may be present at multiple stages in your process. The visible issue is with your Teradata column encoding. Character set ASCII cannot support full range of UTF-8. You must specify the correct encoding in your Teradata table. Also, the mode through which you are loading also matters. I am not familiar with Talend, but if you are using ODBC then session encoding must be set to UTF-8. This may also be the case if you are using Teradata Load/Unload utilities in Talend.

Comment: Also, if you are loading from Teradata to Hive, and the reference file is already present in HDFS (referring to point 1 in the question), then it seems counter intuitive to load first into Teradata then move it into a Hive table. You can simply define an external table in Hive, select from it and move to your target Hive table.